# Onto function and Power set cardinality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need some hints for proving that if $f:A\to B$ is onto $B$, then $P(B)\leq P(A)$. And  $|B|\leq |A|$ under axiom of choice.

Thank you!

Comment: How constructing one-to-one function $F$, where $F:P(B)\to P(A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\hat f\colon P(B)\to P(A)$ by setting $\hat f(X)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in X\}$. You can show this is an injection.

If the axiom of choice holds simply choose from $\hat f(\{b\})$ to construct the injection from $B$ to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

First, try relating the cardinality of $A$ and $B$ by using the information you have.  Then, use that to generalize up to the cardinality of the power sets.

Comment: If A and B are finite sets, I can say that |B|<|A|. But what in the case they aren't?

Comment: Jebruho, relating the cardinalities requires choice.